# ProgressBar error and very slow import in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to import a CSV file into MySQL, but the progress bar doesn't advance.
When I cancel the import, a ProgressBar error appears, but I see that the file was partially imported.
The same error is repeated with other files, and from what everything indicates, besides the ProgressBar error, MySQL is very slow in the import.
I searched the forum and everything indicates that it is a Bug, but it has not yet been resolved by the developers.
Has anyone managed to solve this problem or circumvent it somehow?
I use Windows 10 and the latest version of MySQL.

[image: The way I configure the import]

[image: How the progress bar stays still]

[image: The error]

Comment: *MySQL is very slow in the import* No, this is Workbench problem which reads and inserts row-by-row. Do not use such import, create correct LOAD DATA statement and execute. This is the most fast method for CSV data import.

Answer (score 0):

I see frequent complaints that bulk import in MySQL Workbench is very slow.

https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=95481 (May 2019)

> "Workbench import wizard extremely, agonizingly, painfully slow"

https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=101803 (Nov 2020)

> "MySQL Workbench Table Data Import Wizard is still extremely slow"

I don't know why they even implemented an import function and then made it so bad.

I would recommend using LOAD DATA INFILE with the command-line MySQL client. Do not use MySQL Workbench if you need data import to be fast.

You might also write your own custom script in Python or whatever your favorite language is.

You may be interested in my presentation [Load Data Fast!](https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/load-data-fast)